# Clarification on Elven Wizard favored classs bonus

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard

If one chooses to play an elven wizard the [favored class bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Favored-Class-Bonuses) is stated to be:

> Select one arcane school power at 1st level that is normally usable a number of times per day equal to 3 + the wizard's Intelligence modifier. The wizard adds +½ to the number of uses per day of that arcane school power.

Would this mean that the elven wizard could select an arcane school power other than the one from his initial chosen class and gain both access to that power and the ability to use it 3 + INT + 1/2 times per day?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I expect most GMs mandate that the [elf wizard favored class bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard#TOC-Favored-Class-Bonuses) adds extra uses to an arcane school special ability that the elf wizard *already* possesses. This 2012 [thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2p61d?Elf-wizard-favored-class) on the same topic cites *Pathfinder* designer Jason Bulhman's [post](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5ldw0&page=3?The-FAQ-That-Time-Forgot#141) that says that, essentially, *You can't add something to nothing*. That is, adding +½ to the number of uses of an ability a creature *doesn't* possess doesn't *grant* the creature the ability!

However, a strict legalist *could* argue that the elf wizard favored class bonus specifically says *Select one arcane school power at 1st level that is normally usable a number of times per day equal to 3 + the wizard's Intelligence modifier*, and that sentence does *not* limit the elf wizard *only* to special abilities he's *already* selected, therefore leaving open the option to select *via* the elf wizard favored class bonus a *new*, previously unpossessed arcane school special ability.

For example, an elf wizard that specializes in [abjuration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/abjuration) at level 1 gains the supernatural ability protective ward usable a number of times per day equal to 3 + his Intelligence modifier. At level 1, using the elf wizard favored class bonus, the same elf could select the [universalist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/universalist) wizard supernatural ability hand of the apprentice. However, it would be up to the GM if the elf wizard were, at level 1, able to use the ability hand of the apprentice *either* a number of times per day equal to 3 + his Intelligence modifier *or* 0 times per day (i.e. ½ rounded down), this latter reading stemming from the GM reading the elf wizard favored class bonus number of uses specifically overriding the typical number of uses for the special ability.

Despite this second reading being possible in the *very* abstract, I wouldn't expect any GM to agree with it without substantial persuasion in the form of booze, cash, or pizza.

Answer (score 3):

No, it does not allow access to other powers, because these are not normally usable for someone with your character's specialization at all. All it does is to add one use every two levels.

Even if this would be possible to gain access to other powers, you would only add ½ to your initial use, that is, to 0. But that is really, really generous interpretation.

Comment: It would be good to note that the reason for the somewhat odd wording is for future-proofing of that trait; if a future arcane school granted more than one 1st level power, the wording ensures that only one can be selected.

Comment: The word *normally* in the elf wizard favored class bonus applies to *how often* the ability can be used—hence establishing to which special ability the favored class bonus *can* apply (for example, an [abjurer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/abjuration) can select protective ward but not resistance); that *normally* is *not* defining whether the ability can be used by the wizard *at all.*